# Why display attrib is not working here as float atrrib works

Tags: html, css

In the link below when I try using 'display:table-cell' or 'display:inline-block' instead of 'float:left' then it works same as float attribute but if I click on Remove or Hide button and click on Reset All then two boxes goes to the next line. Why it happens ? Isn't that possible to replace float by display in some scenarios, Is float attribute inevitable ?

Here is the link for the example: [a link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_display)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because inline-block with space between elements cause 3px space, see more about here: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

But on this code, you just need change restore function

```
function resetElement() {
    document.getElementById("imgbox1").style.display = "inline-block"; // HERE
    document.getElementById("imgbox2").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```